# boost iostreams library exist but i am unable link it

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, shared-objects, boost-iostreams

I know that the re plenty of similar questions, but mine is litle bit different and non them helped me.

I am using boost-iostreams library and here is my problem, i tried to link my program with libraries:

```
ld -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/ -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/device/  -L/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so -lboost-iostreams fd.o -o x
```

And the result was:

```
ld: cannot find -lboost-iostreams
```

When i tried to write it explicitly:

```
ld -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/ -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/device/  --library /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so -lboost-iostreams fd.o -o x
```

It told me that the library dont exist:

```
ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
ld: cannot find -lboost-iostreams
```

But it does:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 204682 feb  4 05:28 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 feb  4 05:28 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.a ->         libboost_iostreams.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 feb  4 05:28 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.so ->  libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28 feb  4 05:28 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so -> libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  94280 feb  4 05:28 /usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0
```

About me:

- OS: Debian 7 Wheezy
- prog. lang.: c++
- compiler: g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
- linker: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.22
- boost library ver.: 1.49 ( from debian repo )

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The right option should be `-lboost_iostreams`, not `-lboost-iostreams`

**EDIT2:**

After edit my command was:

```
ld fd.o -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/ -I/usr/include/boost/iostreams/device/ -o x $(LIB_PATH) -lboost_iostreams
```

Where libpath is ONE of following:

```
LIB_PATH=
LIB_PATH=-L/usr/lib/
LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so
LIB_PATH=/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.a
```

but the result is still:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000000000804cc10
fd.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
fd.cpp:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
ld: x: hidden symbol `__dso_handle' isn't defined
ld: final link failed: Bad value
make: *** [x] Error 1
```

Comment: The library is called `libboost_iostreams` with an underscore, but you are trying to link `lboost-iostreams` with a `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking you do not call `ld` directly but rather call `gcc` or `g++` instead. This might add the correct search paths when linking.

If you link explicitly, you must not include the -l flag. Just add `/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.a` or `/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams.so` to the list of files that you are linking.

The `-l` flag add the `lib` prefix and the `.so` or `.a` suffix.

Comment: looks like you are not using gcc or g++ for linking. Don't use ld directly